# How to have permissions to save file into SD Card on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, filesystems, sd-card

I recently created an application in which I share files through an *intent filter*, so that an user can save the shared file in any folder on the system.

The purpose of this app is to share a file from WhatsApp (or any other app) and select through a file explorer the location to save it.

[image: SaveFile app print screen]

It is working correctly for *internal storage*. It is possible to save the file in any folder within that location. However, when selecting the *external storage* folder (external "SD card"), it does not allow saving, and displays a message indicating permission error, throwing the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
  at br.com.luansilveira.savefile.MainActivity.btSalvarClick(MainActivity.java:370)
```

In the application manifest, storage permissions have already been requested:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and when starting app, they are requested for the user.

Below is the code where file is written:

```java
public void btSalvarClick(View view) {
        String filename = diretorioAtual.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + edNomeArquivo.getText().toString();
        try {
            File novoArquivo = new File(diretorioAtual, edNomeArquivo.getText().toString());
            if (!novoArquivo.createNewFile()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "O arquivo já existe!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(novoArquivo);
            outputStream.write(getBytes(uri));
            outputStream.close();

            finish();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Arquivo salvo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sem permissão para salvar neste local", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Erro ao salvar: \n" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, removable micro sd cards are not writable under Android since already Android Kitkat. Only one app specific directory is writable.

Comment: `"O arquivo já existe!"`  No. That should be: "File cannot be created.".

Comment: @blackapps but then how does ES File Explorer app write files into external SD Card?

Comment: Then it has to use SAF. Didnt it once ask the user to indicate the removable micro sd card?  You can use SAF too to write to a removable micro SD card.